# PHP on Submit check for records, if record exist 'confirm' update or insert new if no record

Tags: php

I am having trouble figuring out how to correctly execute the following problem. I have a web form that my user will fill out, this form has (ajax that populates the account user will work with aka admin).

Before submission of the new data I would like to verify if that account already has data, if data exists I need to have a confirmation to override the current data. If there is no data nothing happens (new data just gets inserted into the db).

This is the flow of the page,

1) (Ajax) Input -> Find account,
2) Once account selected enter data (no refresh between the two steps)
3) Submit data -> Still on same page (looking if Input Exists and executes Insert)

Is it possible to have some sort of confirmation inside the try / catch before submission.

Code:

```
if(Input::exists()){
    try{
       if(row exists){
        // Confirm here if row exists to override or cancel SUBMIT
       }else{ // insert new }
```

Why I need this is because accounts are allowed to have only 1 of this kind of record, and I don't want them to accidentally override existing record (if it exists).

Thanks

Comment: so what do u want from here?

Comment: I believe you are using Laravel so try something like this: $row_exists = count(DB::table("table_name")->where("something", "=", "something")->get);
Then you can check if $row_exists > 0 // it exists else // it doesn't exists

Comment: If you are uncomfortable writing simple PHP scripts, combining it with learning ajax isn't going to do you any favours

Comment: Your post is very confusing, but I guess you are looking for some kind of user confirmation. This can be achieved only with 2 separate steps: make 1st request to server to check if data already exists and eventually ask for confirmation, then make a 2nd request to the server to actually update/insert data. Just to clarify better: a PHP script is just that, a script. The idea is that some code is executed server side and generates a response. You can't place any user interaction *inside* the execution, you'd need multiple requests for that.

Comment: I am not using frame work I am doing everything from scratch. I tried using ajax to get row once company is selected however I am not having much success.I believe the best way would be to have some confirmation inside try statement but I don't know how to do that. And I was unable to find any resource that explains that approach

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to solve it, what I did was onclick of account that would fill the INPUT BOX; I would than use ajax to check for the rows of selected account. If row was found I would ask for confirmation using jQuery `confirm` and if clicked OK I would populate HIDDEN input with value `1`. So on submit it would check if the hidden field is 1 or 0 if 1 that would mean its an update of existing record and if 0 it would create new one.